# How can I read a value from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I ask now apologize for the issue that I will do, but already searched everywhere and found nothing relevant.

I need to read a data from a website, but not even managed to do.

The information is as follows:
[image]

And I need to read the numbers.

Did I could help please?

Thank you all.

If you need I clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Very vague and unclear but it looks like json data so... how is this data retrieved? Is this a simple webpage loaded in a browser or the result from some ajax / rest request?

You could try using DOMDocument and then searching the DOM for the PRE tag and getting the contents that way.

If it is a json response from an ajax call then it is a trivial task. More info is required to get a sensible answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. this is a simple webpage loaded in a browser. And what I need is read that number to sendo from a page made by me. you understand my question now? Sorry for that